# VisualForce, Listing Two Objects on a "single" Page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have read most tutorials and googled a lot, with no success...

Let's assume that I have Two DB objects.

I'd like to have a "single page" that lists their records side-by-side. The result will looks like a grid UI.

Is it possible at all? I know that we can have an "extension controller" that takes care of some customized controller. I'm still wondering how I can retrieve records from TWO objects in a single controller ...

Any Suggestion, please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide more details, because I don't see any complex in here.

Controller:

```
sObject obj1 {get;set;}
sObject obj1 {get;set;}

void methodName() {
 obj1 = [select ... ];
 obj2 = [select ... ];
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="blablablaController" 
    title="blabla"
    sidebar="false"
>

    <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!(errorMessage != null)}" summary="{!errorMessage}" severity="warning" strength="2" />

    <apex:form id="blaForm" >

        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:outputText value="{!obj1.field1}" 
                        style="
                            font-weight:bold;
                            font-size:large;
                        "
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!obj2.field1}" 
                        style="
                            font-weight:bold;
                            font-size:large;
                        "
                    />
...
```

and so on...

Please, give us more information of what you are trying to achieve. Because as for me this solution is obvious.

Comment: Thanks .. I found my solution here. As you mentioned I have to set a Custom Controller which can handle both Objects : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/multiple-custom-objects-in-a-single-visualforce-page